# jQuery Accordion multiple column not behaving accurately

Tags: css-float, multiple-columns, jquery-ui-accordion

**Scenario:** I have created a simple 2 columns jQuery accordion with 56 `<li>` elements. In reality it may have 200 or many more items who knows ;) It's repeating `<li>` in a loop

Try the fiddle. It's cool! https://jsfiddle.net/srmahmud2/smtn6gt0/9/ [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/srmahmud2/smtn6gt0/9/)

Way I have done it: made li float left, with 15px padding to make some space in between.

**Target:** Make a proper behaved multi column jQuery accordion

**Problem:**

1. For example the clicking on number 1 item on the left will expand but most of the items form left will automatically go to right which is not desired.
2. Now click on number 3. While expanding and after finished expanding this will again come back to left. So you will not have it under your mouse pointer to click again to collapse or click again to expand any of its child items. Try all the odd number before the last item.
3. Clicking on any items on right before the last item will expand it; but this will open a white/blank space on the left as well.